# Worksheet.Change event (excel) is not invoking sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

The worksheet.change event is not triggering some of the time. I don't get any idea what is the reason behind this.

Here is my code:

```
 case "Briefing":
  Worksheet briefingSheet = BerifingSheet.LoadSheet(finalWorkbook.Sheets["Briefing"], loginResult, campaignResult);

  //Making briefing sheet active. 
  briefingSheet.Activate();

  Event_CellsChange_brief = new Excel.DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler(BriefingSheet_Change);

  briefingSheet.Change += Event_CellsChange_brief;

  break;
```

Comment: edit your question instead please. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)